# How to consistently release shift key when using Java Robot?

Tags: java

I'm using Robot in Java to do some inputs, but if I type the inputs too quickly the shift key does not release. How can I assure that it releases consistently?

I've tried using a sleep function.
I've tried releasing multiple times.

```java
public class Input {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException, InterruptedException {
        Robot robot = new Robot();

        while (true) {

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            String input = scanner.nextLine();
            char position = input.charAt(0);
            int ascii = Integer.valueOf(input.substring(1));
            System.out.print(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
            int keycode = KeyEvent.getExtendedKeyCodeForChar(Integer.valueOf(input.substring(1)));
            if (ascii == 16) {
                keycode = KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT;
            }
            char val;

            if (position == 'D') {

                robot.keyPress(keycode);

            } else if (position == 'U') {

                robot.keyRelease(keycode);

            }
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
    }
}
```

If I type D16, 16 being the ascii value of shift, it will hold down the shift button until I say U16, which will lift it. This only works sometimes. The way to run the input is by hitting enter. If I type in multiple inputs in a really short span of time, the shift release doesn't register. What am I doing wrong here?